# What does the level of put call ratio of SPX tells you about the impending S&P 500 movement?

Tags: options, spx

I have been following a YouTube channel and noticed that a high level of put-call ratio can be used to explain regardless of whether the S&P closes in the red or green.

1. Market closes in the green --> Shorts are covering --> High put call ratio explains this mvt
2. Market closes in the red --> Bearish sentiments --> High put call ratio also explains this.

As such, I'm confused on what to make of based on this put call indicator

Comment: Disregard it (unless you have done your own research showing that it works, and personally I doubt it does). It would be a good quant project for you to do a statistical analysis, though. Have fun!

Comment: I would like to understand if both statements regarding the Put Call Ratio indicator are theoretically sound.

Comment: No - it is not theoretically sound. That is not how scientific reasoning works. The statements you heard on Youtube have no theoretical or empirical basis. It is people making up nonsense to make themselves look smart. Have I answered your question? ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.